# Custom Messages for validation annotaions

Tags: java, playframework, internationalization, annotations

These annotations gives these default messages:

```
@Required                //error.required
@MinLength(1)            //error.minlength   
@MaxLength(10)           //error.maxlength
private String name;
```

I want to change these messages, it will be better if it will comes from messages file.

I tried:

```
@Required(message=Messages.get("requiredError"))
```

but it was saying:

> The value for annotation attribute Constraints.Required.message must
>   be a constant expression

Any-other way to achieve this?

I am using play framework 2.3.7

Answer (score 0):

The following line should work:

`@Required(message="requiredError")`

Assuming your messages-file (`conf/messages` or `conf/messages.XX` for the translations) contains an entry:

`requiredError=My Message....`

Comment: i tried your answer but its shownig requiredError not the message

Comment: does the messages file contain an entry for "requiredError"? (for each language?)

Comment: no, i have not created message file for all languages

Comment: Is it present in the language currently displayed?

Comment: i have two message files(messages and messages.en) and some properties file in conf
both message file having `requiredError=must have a value`

Comment: I went over the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaI18N) and apparantly you need to add an entry to the configuration file (`conf(application.conf`) as well:
`application.langs="en,fr"` (for English and French for example)